# How to pass Any object as a Json Writeable in Scala?

Tags: json, scala

For this function call:

```
fakeRequest(controllers.routes.GPInviteService.invite, Json.toJson(i))
```

Which is defined as:

```
def fakeRequest(target: () => Call, json: JsValue): Any
```

I would like to simplify the calling code, and eliminate the need to create the Json object. So, the call would become:

```
fakeRequest(controllers.routes.GPInviteService.invite, i)
```

And the function would then become:

```
def fakeRequest(target: () => Call, i: Any): Any = {
    route(FakeRequest(target()).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(i))) match {
                                                         ^
    ...
```

But this gets me a compile error, because toJson() wants a Writes[A] type. I'm not familiar enough with Scala and the Json library to figure out how I can pass in essentially any object for i, given that it must implement an implicit Writes. (I tried passing `i: Writes` but that doesn't work).

Comment: Can't work because `Any` doesn't have any useful type information. How about parameterizing `fakeRequest`?  eg. `def fakeRequest[A](target: () => Call, i: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]): A = ???`

Comment: I don't understand that syntax... but, after a little tinkering I got it to work. I'll post my answer below.

Comment: Someone beat me to it. The `(implicit w: Writes[A]): A = ???` didn't work, but I'm thinking perhaps you did not mean to literally include "???" but rather my function. But this did work: `def fakeRequest[A](target: () => Call, i: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]): Any = { ... }` so thank you! Top marks to @daniel-c-sobral for clarity and simplicity tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
def fakeRequest[A: Writes](target: () => Call, i: A): Any = {
```

The function call to `Json.toJson`, according to the error message, takes an implicit parameter of type `Writes[A]`, for a parameter of type `A`. Most importantly, this means you cannot pass `Any` -- the type *must* be statically known at the point the method is called, and `Writes[A]` makes that information available at run time (since type parameters are erased).

The syntax `[A: Writes]` tells Scala that you want an implicit parameter of type `Writes[A]`, in addition to the normal parameters. This implicit will be then passed on to the call to `Json.toJson`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
def fakeRequest[A](target: () => Call, i: A)(implicit writes: Writes[A]): A = { ...
```

this way you can pass any A,provided that you also pass implicitly a Writes instance for it (a way to serialize it). Or you could define a Writes for Any (I'm not sure how you can do that, it means to have a serializer for any possible object) and follow Daniel's answer

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I appreciate the hints on Scala syntax. Still learning...